# jQuery to expand text on hover

Tags: php, jquery, text, hover, css-tables

On our website, we currently display description text by fetching data from the cloud provider and displaying it in tables. However, sometimes we want the description to be longer, but it exceeds the available area and our CSS defines overflow to ellipsis. I'm looking to add jQuery code to expand the hidden text on hover, but without messing with the table row height or width. A CSS solution I tried to edit height on hover wouldn't work without increasing the height of the row.

Would be great if the hidden text could just popover the existing text by staying on top of all other elements. The popover should also automatically go to a new line after a certain width, thus the popover could even have to stay on top of rows below. A border or shadow around the popover would be nice.

I'm new to Javascript, jQuery and web coding in general but I can handle this stuff. I've tried a couple of examples for hover from around the web but couldn't get them to work for me.

Here's how it currently looks with randomly filled data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a jquery tooltip plugin. You can also achieve a similar effect by setting the title attribute with the full contents of the title
Try jquery ui tooltip http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/

Its a bit of an overkill to have jquery UI just for the tooltip. So you can search others on google

Comment: I like how the default tooltip looks. I was also able to move the tooltip so I think I can make it pop out exactly over the description td element. However, if it will only work with tooltip (title) elements I'm not sure how I can use it with a TD element.

Comment: you an use the title attribute on any element `<td title="Something">Data</td>`

Comment: Thank you. I moved the tooltip to overlap over the td element. However, a bug (or is it a feature?) of the tooltip is that on hover, it blinks a couple of times before staying steady. Is there any other jquery UI trick that could achieve something similar?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I finally got it working using "Poshytip" http://vadikom.com/tools/poshy-tip-jquery-plugin-for-stylish-tooltips/ which has all necessary arguments for my specific case.

Not enough rep to vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this type of mechanism:

```
<a class="zoom" href='#' style='font-size:12px;top:50px;left:50px'>Hover me!</a>
```

main

```
.zoom {
      -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
              transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    }
    .zoom:hover {
      -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
              transform: scale(1.4);
    }
```

then for ellipsis you can use small example code:

```
<ul>
<li><span class="icon"></span>Long Text with text-overflow:ellipsis</li>
<li><span class="icon"></span>Short text</li>
<li><span class="icon"></span>Long Text with text-overflow:ellipsis</li>
</ul>
```

and css

```
.icon {
height:18px;
width:18px;
background:url(http://www.darkroomart.com/dewolfe/css/images/dw-icons.png);
float:right;
cursor:pointer;
background-position:-72px -72px;
display: block;
}
.icon:hover {
background-position:-90px -72px;
}
li {
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    height:20px;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    list-style-type:none;
    width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm not looking to zoom in/out on the text. I want to show the text that's hidden by the ellipsis on hover. Sorry for the confusion !

Comment: That doesn't seem to do anything, or I'm unable to use it properly. Also the darkroomart URL asks for a password so I removed that property.